# Facing difficulties in Installing Mobius in Window environment?

Tags: c#, apache-spark, mobius

I am basically a .net programmer and I am tasked with analyzing data with SPARK and Cassandra. I was looking for a C# API to work with SPARK and I found out Mobius (as I don’t know JAVA). I started downloading the Mobius project, from GitHub and as per the build for windows I followed the steps mentioned and not able to get it work. I have the following questions regarding it.

1)  I have a DataStax enterprise in an Ubuntu machine where my Cassandra and SPARK is available (Standalone). Now I would like to connect from my .NET project to the SPARK and then process the data in Cassandra. Is it possible for me to do that? I want to do that in Debug mode? I will be working using SPARK-SQL only as i am comfortable in SQL.

2)  Is it a MUST to install SOLR and SPARK in my windows machine in order for Mobius to work? Will I be able to connect to CASSANDRA (Ubuntu machine) from the Windows SPARK and Mobius?

3)  When I run the the command “**sparkclr-submit.cmd debug**” to get the value for **CSharpBackendPortNumber**, I am getting an error that “**load-spark-env.cmd**” is missing. Where can I find this file and how will I get the value for CSharpBackendPortNumber? Is it necessary to have SPARK in my windows machine?

Comment: My apologies for the late non-reply. I post this here to help others finding a supported way for use .NET with Apache Spark. 

Microsoft just released a dataframe based .NET support for Apache Spark via the .NET Foundation OSS. See http://dot.net/spark for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using Windows client to connect to YARN-based Spark cluster in Linux is a supported/validated scenario for Mobius. I have never tried using a Windows client for Mobius with Standalone Linux-based Spark cluster. I recommend using a Linux machine as Mobius client to verify a basic functionality in Mobius first.
2. Mobius does not need Solr. You should be able to use Mobius to connect to Cassandra deployed in any OS.
3. load-spark-env.cmd is a part of the Spark release. You need to set SPARK_HOME environment variable before running sparkclr-submit.cmd